# Assets Transform returns "Image cannot be found."

Tags: assets, image-transforms, error

I have two assets sources, Slideshow and Products. I have six Image Transforms.

On the home page I'm using a structure channel to play a simple slideshow and I'm using 3 transforms and all is working fine.

This code works fine:

```
{{ entry.productPhotos.first().geturl() }}
```

But this code throws an error:

```
{{ entry.productPhotos.first().geturl('productSlide') }}
```

[image: error message]

If you go on my assets source path, the file is uploaded but the transform folder doesn't exist.

I tried clearing cache, deleting records in `craft_assettransformindex`, and most of the things suggested here, but with no luck. The weird thing is that the other Structure with the assets Slideshow works fine so it couldn't be something with the paths.

I'm using `'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true`, in my `config/general.php` file.

You can see on my phpMyAdmin screenshot that the filename is NULL in the table `craft_assettransformindex` but all the other transforms for the slideshow are there:

[image: db row]

Comment: Hi Dimitrios, welcome to Stack Exchange. Hope you don't mind, I cleaned up your post a little. Specifically, I rolled your comment and linked error into the original post, to make it easier for anyone else trying to troubleshoot this same problem. :)

Comment: Thanks I couldn't add 2 images because of my reputation which limits me to 1 link per post.

Comment: It was obvious that it was a path problem. I changed the path from assets/photos/products/ to ../assets/photos/products/ and now it's working fine. But could someone explain me why do i needed the ../ since the other assets were working without it? Could it be something to do with the environmental variables? Cheers

Comment: Now I cannot upload images because the path is wrong....

Answer (score 4):

A long shot, but if it is indeed a path problem, this has seemed to help me keep my path(s) straight. I my `config.php` file, I'll set a parameter for `environmentVariables` like this:

```
...

'.dev' => array(
    'devMode' => true,
    'siteUrl' => 'http://mysite.dev/',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'basePath' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/',
        'baseUrl' => 'http://mysite.dev/',
    )
)

...
```

Then when you are defining your asset sources, you can use this for "File System Path":

```
{basePath}assets/photos/products/
```

Then for URL try this:

```
/assets/photos/products
```