# CP transform renders image 404

Tags: image-transforms

I have a transform in my CP called detail large.
IN my template the image will render normally.

```
<img class="img-fluid"  src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" >
```

Wen i want to use the transform like below:

```
<img class="img-fluid"  src="{{ image.getUrl('detailLarge') }}" >
```

I get a 404.

The image path created for the transformed asset is:

```
/webroot/assets/images/_detailLarge
```

but not folder or assets is ever created there.
Permissions and aliases are fine.

Comment: What happens if you put a transform code in instead of the named transform? `{{ image.getUrl({width: 200, height: 200}) }}`? Also, have you checked [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13734/assets-transform-returns-image-cannot-be-found?rq=1)

Comment: Same issue with that. The path problem sounds reasonable line of inquiry but it all seems set up fine and I have quite a few setup with .env variables for general config

Answer (score 1):

Solved - was a local path issue